# Strange behavior with todatetime function

Tags: azure-data-explorer

```
| extend CommandTimeStamp = tostring(customDimensions['CommandTimeStamp'])
| extend originalValue = CommandTimeStamp
| extend constantValue = "11/16/2021 6:04:17 AM +00:00"
| project originalValue, constantValue, equals = (CommandTimeStamp == constantValue), originalTime = CommandTimeStamp, timeColum1 = todatetime(constantValue), timeColum2 = todatetime(CommandTimeStamp)
```

Get Result:
[image]

The last column is empty. It is strange.
Can someone explain it? It blocks us a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the list of supported datetime formats is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime

the format you're using isn't included in that list, and you may want to first manipulate it in the origin, or using query functions, prior to casting it using `todatetime()`

the fact that casting the constant string literal works is because it's handled in a separate code path, that (currently) happens to support undocumented formats.

Comment: Make sense. But the behavior should keep align regardless of whether this parameter is constant or not. Maybe there exists some "Json deserialization issue with DateTime" in the code.

Comment: It's not our data, so, manipulate  it in the origin is impossible. You said using query functions, what does it mean, you mean I could use something string related functions(such like split, concat) to handler the datetime?

Comment: i meant using string functions/operators in order to change the value from an unsupported format to a supported one. for example: `T
| extend dt = todatetime(substring(s, 0, strlen(s)-6))` (this removes the trailing ` +00:00`)